# Distance of closest approach

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, metric-tensor

When deriving the gravitational bending angle of light, In this [paper](http://home.fnal.gov/~syphers/Education/Notes/lightbend.pdf), the author introduced $R$ (the distance of closest approach), in equation ($7$), to solve the problem.

My question: How is $R$ defined in terms of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: It's  a pdf file, it won't work on some phones or tablets,  would you consider putting the relevant equations in your post?

Comment: @AcidJazz, Here are the first two pages as jpg files 
$$$$
Page 1
$$$$
http://i.imgur.com/R1ygl0V.jpg 
$$$$
Page 2
$$$$
http://i.imgur.com/owpwi5T.jpg

Comment: Thanks,I hate to bug you about this, but the easier you make the question, the better chance you have of getting an answer. You could use the graphics button and put those images in your post, but most people will say "use mathjax" so they can copy and post it in any possible answer. Up to you, of course.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that all you have to do is integrate (6) to obtain:
$$\alpha = \int dx \frac{2GM}{c^2}\frac{y}{(x^2+y^2)^\frac{3}{2}} = \frac{2GM}{c^2}\frac{xy}{y^2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{2GM}{c^2}\frac{x}{y\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \equiv \frac{4GM}{c^2R}$$
So we obtain:
$$R=\frac{2y\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{x}$$

Comment: But, why is this called the distance of closest approach?

Comment: R is the solar radius. Any light closer to the origin (the centre of the sun) will not be visible.